# Can you access the DOM children of an element using JS?

Tags: javascript

What I would like to do:

```
var myDIv = document.getElementById('myDivID');
myDIv.getImmediateChildren;
```

Comment: use myDIv.children to access the children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all children, use :

```
myDiv.children
```

example here : https://jsfiddle.net/vgncd96t/

-

To get the first child, use :

```
myDiv.firstElementChild
```

example here : https://jsfiddle.net/vgncd96t/1/

-

To get the last child, use :

```
myDiv.lastElementChild
```

example here : https://jsfiddle.net/vgncd96t/2/

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
var children = document.getElementById('myDivID').childNodes
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this

```
 var myDIv = document.getElementById('myDivID');
 myDIv.Children;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
var myDIv = document.getElementById('myDivID');
var children = myDiv.children;
```

That will get you all children of the element.

There are even more options, like if you want only the first child, you can do:

```
var firstChild = myDiv.firstElementChild;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("myDivID").children[0]
```

will give you the first immediate child element